# How can I correct this Java code taken from a tutorial?

Tags: java, formatting

I copied this code into Eclipse from a learn java app (Codemurai) but I am getting errors.  As I am new to Java I am not sure about structuring, so I tried it 2 different ways.  As given:-

```
String name;
int weaponDamage;
int health;
double score;

Player codemurai = new Player();
codemurai.name = "Codemurai";
codemurai.weaponDamage = 100;
codemurai.health = 100;
codemurai.score = 1500;
```

I tried this way:-

```
public class Player {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    int weaponDamage;
    int health;
    double score;
    
    Player codemurai = new Player();
    codemurai.name = "Codemurai";
    codemurai.weaponDamage = 100;
    codemurai.health = 100;
    codemurai.score = 1500;
}
}
```

and get "name cannot be resolved" on the last lines.

Then I tried this:-

```java
public class Player {
    String name;
    int weaponDamage;
    int health;
    double score;
    
    Player codemurai = new Player();
    codemurai.name = "Codemurai";
    codemurai.weaponDamage = 100;
    codemurai.health = 100;
    codemurai.score = 1500;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    }
}
```

and get "VariableDeclaratorID expected".

I know there will not be any output from this code, but how do I make it run error-free, and what do these errors actually mean?

Comment: [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Thank you - fair point.  I could see that the title wasn't great but as a new user I don't really have the language to know how to frame the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class Player {
    String name;
    int weaponDamage;
    int health;
    double score;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player codemurai = new Player();
        codemurai.name = "Codemurai";
        codemurai.weaponDamage = 100;
        codemurai.health = 100;
        codemurai.score = 1500;
    }
}
```

When variables are declared inside a method, they are local to that method. It appears you want the variables `name`, `weaponDamage`, `health` and `score` to be members of class `Player`. Hence you must declare them outside of the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the @Abra solution is to create a Player class that only contains the attributes and Question's class instantiate one Player.

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

class Player {
    String name;
    int weaponDamage;
    int health;
    double score;
}

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player codemurai = new Player();
        codemurai.name = "Codemurai";
        codemurai.weaponDamage = 100;
        codemurai.health = 100;
        codemurai.score = 1500;
    }
}
```